# javascript: use ajax string to create object

Tags: javascript, ajax, object

In a javascript function, if I set:

```
var listnames = {
    "lista": {name: "ListA"},
    "listb": {name: "ListB"},
    "listc": {name: "ListC"},
};
console.log(listnames);
```

the console shows: [object Object].

However, if I build the same text in php and retrieve it using ajax like this:

```
function set_listnames() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: form_handler, // a php script
        data: '&action=get_listnames',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        listnames = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('listnames (after parse): ' + listnames);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log ('failed');
    });
```

the response text from the post in the console shows: "{\"lista\":{name:\"ListA\"},\"listb\":{name:\"ListB\"},\"listc\":{name:\"ListC\"}}"

and after parsing the console shows the string (same as the hardcoded values above): 
{"lista":{name:"ListA"},"listb":{name:"ListB"},"listc":{name:"ListC"}}

I need the returned string to be evaluated as [object Object] in order for a plugin function I'm using to work.

How do I transform the ajax returned string into an object?

Comment: I think you already did. It's just that occasionally, JavaScript's toString method isn't as useless as it usually is. Try `typeof listnames` to verify the result is what you want.

Comment: console.log(typeof listnames) is 'string'. I need it to be object.

Comment: Wow, really? You need to file a critical bug with the browser you were testing with, then, to inform them that their JSON.parse method is returning the wrong type completely. Or, well, maybe you didn't debug that quite right, or your code isn't just as you wrote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response from server the key "name" without quotes.
Should be

```
{"name": "LisaA"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The plugin requires the name to be unquoted.  See the very top which works fine.

Comment: After hours of trial and error, this was closest to the right answer.  I ultimately did put quotes around the "name" in the PHP string and that fixed the problem...even though the plugin documentation and demos clearly showed that no quotes were needed.  I now see that when you create an object by doing this: `var a = {name: "value"}`, you don't need the quotes, but when you are converting a string to an object via JSON.parse, the 'name' in the string to be converted must be quoted. Newbie mistake perhaps...noting it for others.

Comment: Wnen you use `var a = {name: ''123a"}` it's a javascript object very similar by syntax to JSON. When you get JSON by AJAX it should be a real JSON format with keys is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You're 100% sure the first example shows `[object Object]`? In which browser(s) are you testing?

If you really need the parsed response to be `[object Object]`, you can do this:

```
console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call( listnames ) );
```

But as far as wanting `listnames` to be an object... it already is.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I'm 100% sure the first example show [object Object]. I tried to post a picture of the firebug log output but I guess that's not possible in SO.  I'm not familiar with the "Object..." code you posted.  What does that do?  Should I use it like this:  `listnames = Object.prototype.toString.call( listnames );`

Comment: Also... curious why you say that listnames is already an object?  typeof reports it as string

Comment: When you do `listnames = JSON.parse( data )`, it is an object. That's what I was referring to. After `listnames = Object.prototype.toString.call( listnames )`, it is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  For some reason listnames after JSON.parse is still a string... :(

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or argumentative, but the value returned from `JSON.parse()` is not ever going to be a string. `JSON.parse()` can do one of two things: It can return an `Object`, or it can raise an exception. Try `console.log( typeof JSON.parse( data ) )`.

Comment: Not taken as rude or argumentative at all.  Your explanation was very helpful and ultimately lead me to the answer!  Thanks.